# Python: List to ints to a single number?

Tags: python, list

Say i have a several list if ints:

```
x =  [['48', '5', '0'], ['77', '56', '0'],
['23', '76', '34', '0']]
```

I want this list to be converted to a single number, but the the single number type is still an integer i.e.:

```
4850775602376340
```

i have been using this code to carry out the process:

```
num = int(''.join(map(str,x)))
```

but i keep getting a value error.

Also if my list contained negative integers how would i convert them to there absolute value? Then convert them to a single number?

> x2 =  [['48', '-5', '0'], ['77', '56',
>   '0'],
>       ['23', '76', '-34', '0']]
>
> x2 = 4850775602376340

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a list of lists, so

```
num = int(''.join(''.join(l) for l in lists))
```

or

```
def flatten( nested ):
    for inner in nested:
        for x in inner:
            yield x

num = ''.join(flatten(lists))
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer a little more? I don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> int(''.join(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, x)))
4850775602376340
```

Comment: just another quick question how woould i raise and error if the single number didnt contain and integer?

Comment: @harpalss: you can loop through the items and check type(i)==int if you want to make sure

Comment: The int()-call will raise a ValueError in that case.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.itertools.chain.from_iterable) for this (new in python 2.6)

Example code:

```
import itertools
x = [['48', '5', '0'], ['77', '56', '0'], ['23', '76', '34', '0']]
print int(''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> int(''.join(j for i in x for j in i))
4850775602376340
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = [['48', '5', '0'], ['77', '56', '0'], ['23', '76', '34', '0']]
>>> int(''.join([''.join(i) for i in x ] ))
4850775602376340
```

Comment: And to turn it into an actual int, wrap the `int()` call around it.

Answer (score 1):

Enough good answers already ... just wanted to add the treatment of unlimited nesting:

```
def flatten(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        return obj
    else:
        return ''.join([flatten(x) for x in obj])

>>> x = [['48', '5', '0'], ['77', '56', '0'], ['23', '76', '34', '0']]
>>> flatten(x)
'4850775602376340'

>>> x = [['48', '5', '0'], ['77', '56', '0'], [['23','123'], '76', '34', '0']]
>>> flatten(x)
'4850775602312376340'
```

Answer (score 1):

simply put:

1. flattening the list

   ```
   [e for e in (itertools.chain(*x))]
   ```
2. removing the negative sign

   ```
   e.replace('-','')
   ```
3. joining the numbers in a list into a string and turning it into a number

   ```
   int(''.join(x))
   ```

putting it all together

```
x2 = int(''.join([e.replace('-','') for e in (itertools.chain(*x))]))
```